# How to track events in VB6

Tags: events, vb6, focus

I'm working in a project that unfortunately is written in VB6. =P
I'd like to know if there's any way in VB6 to track a event sender.
My problem is that i have a text field which is receiving focus from someplace i don't know.
I've already mapped all the related events but couldn't figure out where the hell this focus is comming from. Can someone help me on that? =)

Comment: The focus can be send to another control, that has the property (I don't remember the name), that don't allow it to receive focus, so It pass to the next control. Check it.

Comment: I've already thought about that, but the main problem is that passing focus to the next control in the tabindex list is a unwanted effect too...

Comment: I was referring, that you should check that another control is not receiving the focus, and passing it to the text box.

Comment: Hummm i see. I'm gonna check it out =)

Comment: Thers a payment form, then the user presses f5 to give a discount, then a login is required to give access to the discount frame. The login is shown in another form, that calls the payment form back...

Comment: Ok, is impossible to tell the problem from that description. A full read of source code would be needed to correct it. Maybe you want this to be move to a chat room?

Comment: Ok, no problem then... I'm gonna beat my head a little bit more... And if needed i'll come back here. Thanks anyway for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a thread-level hook to intercept WM_GOTFOCUS and WM_LOSTFOCUS messages.